# LinkedList update fails c programming

Tags: c, list, hyperlink

I'm trying to implement simple LinkedList in C, using two structs. Then, my goal is to print the data that is stored in the linkedlist's head.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "LineParser.h"
#include <limits.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define SYS_OPEN  5
#define SYS_CLOSE 6
#define SYS_READ  3
#define SYS_WRITE 4
#define SYS_lseek 19

#define STDOUT 1
#define STDIN  0
#define STDERR 2

char buf[2048];

typedef struct pair {
    char *name;
    char *value;
} pair;

typedef struct pList {
    pair *curPair;
    struct pList *next;
} pList;

pList *head;

void addLink(pList *link);

void addLink(pList *link) {
    if (head == NULL) { //head empty
        head = link;
    } else {
        pList *curLink = head;
        while (curLink->next != NULL) {
            curLink = curLink->next;
        }
        curLink->next = link;
    }
}

void print() {
    printf("%s", head->curPair->name);
}

void dummyFunc() {
    pair *p = (pair *)malloc(sizeof(pair));
    p->name = "User1";
    p->value = "123";
    pList *link = (pList *)malloc(sizeof(pList));
    link->curPair = p;
    link->next = NULL;
    addLink(link);
    head = (pList *)malloc(sizeof(pList));
    head->curPair = p;
    head->next = NULL;
    print();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char argVals[3];
    argVals[2] = '\0';
    //init the list
    head = NULL;

    while (1 == 1) {
        fgets(buf, 2048, stdin);
        if (strcmp(buf, "dummy") == 0) {
            dummyFunc();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when the `print` function is executed (called from `dummyFunc`) the program gets a segfault, implying that the changes that occurred in `dummyFunc` didn't actually effect `head`.

Comment: Please put the `printf` into the code to complete the program. See [mcve].

Comment: Where are you printing?  I don't see an error. Except for the fact that you are reassigning `head` to a `malloc` call after you call `addLink` --> which will destroy your current linked list and cause a memory leak.  Anyway, compiling your code I get "User1" as expected as output.

Comment: edited @MFisherKDX

Comment: `fgets` leaves the newline stored in the buffer. Try `if (strcmp(buf, "dummy\n") == 0)` instead and see if your output changes. This is also something a debugger would be able to show you.

Comment: How is it related to the tag  `hyperlink`?

Answer (score 1):

There is something you are not telling use, because it is highly unlikely `if (strcmp(buf, "dummy") == 0)` matches. You would need to have input exactly `dummy` **without** a trailing newline for the comparison to return `0` and for `dummyFunc()` to be called!

Furthermore, why do you overwrite `head` with a new allocated node instead of calling `addLink` as you did just before? This is causing a memory leak but no segmentation fault, unless `malloc()` is configured to fail.